# Changing Image source of level icon

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to make a Quiz Game for Windows Phone. The Game has many Levels. You can see all Levels in a single Level menu.

**Now my Problem:**

When I complete a Level, how I can change the Image source from the Level Icon?

There two pages : `Levels.xaml` *(This is my level menu)* and `RightLevel.xaml` *(this is the page that appears when you have completed the level correctly)*.

When `RightLevel.xaml` appears I want to change the Image Source from one of the Level Icons in `Levels.xaml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have completed the level you could define a `public bool` as true, so then when you navigate back to the Levels page use an `if` statement to determine whether the level is complete and change the source of the Image using something like `Image.Source = "/AppName;component/Images/ImageName"`

So in c# for the Levels.xaml.cs page it should look something like:

```
if(level1Complete = true)
{
    Image.Source = "/AppName;component/Images/ImageName";
}
```

And in the completed level page:

```
public bool level1Complete = true;
```

Alternativly you can use isolated storage to store files on which levels are complete which would probably be a more efficient way of storing the data.

Note sure how much that helps, but I hope it does

Comment: Im a beginner. Where I have to put the                                      if(level1Complete = true)
{
    Image.Source = "/AppName;component/Images/ImageName";
}                                                           ???  I want to run it when the page is loaded.